# How to get DBpedia ontology classes as JSON or JSON-LD?

Tags: dbpedia

I would like to get class information from DBpedia in a machine-readable format (like JSON).

For example, how do I get [this](http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/Galaxy) page as JSON or JSON-LD?

I did find [this](http://web.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/DBpediaAsTables/DBpedia-en-2016-04/json/Galaxy.json.gz) JSON file, but it doesn't contain the properties.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the ontology file?
Published alongside each release in .nt and .owl

For 2016-10:

- http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-10/dbpedia_2016-10.owl
- http://downloads.dbpedia.org/2016-10/dbpedia_2016-10.nt

Then just query for http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Galaxy

Something [like](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fdomain%20%3Fprop%0D%0AWhere%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fclass%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%7B0%2C1%7D%20%3Fdomain.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fprop%20rdfs%3Adomain%20%3Fdomain.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%3Fclass%20%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FGalaxy%3E%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20):

```
select ?domain ?prop
Where{
    ?class rdfs:subClassOf{0,1} ?domain.
    ?prop rdfs:domain ?domain.
    FILTER(?class = <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Galaxy>)
}
```

*UPDATE*

For json output append &format=json or &format=json-ld: [click](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fdomain%20%3Fprop%0D%0AWhere%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fclass%20rdfs%3AsubClassOf%7B0%2C1%7D%20%3Fdomain.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fprop%20rdfs%3Adomain%20%3Fdomain.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%3Fclass%20%3D%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FGalaxy%3E%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20&format=json).

Comment: Linked Data content negotiation is also an option: `curl -L -H "Accept: application/ld+json,application/json,*/*;q=0.1"  http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Galaxy`